# Unable to build simple Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have created a Rake Task, called *update_zendesk_rake.rb* file, but every time I try to run it with the command

```
rake zendesk:update_zendesk_rake
```

I receive the error:

```
    rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'zendesk:update_zendesk_rake' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `invoke_task'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/conorquarry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

Nor does it show up when I list available tasks, which leads me to believe it's broken, however, I can't see where the error is.

**app/_modules/ccenter/rake/update_zendesk_rake.rb**

```
   namespace :zendesk do
  desc 'update status group values'
  task update_zendesk_rake: :environment do

    the_map = {
      "yssse_ra"=>"legal",
      "active"=>"active",
      "after"=>"legal",
      
    }

    the_map.each { |k,v| CaseFileStatus.where(state: k).update_all(zendesk_status_group: v) }
  end
end
```

Comment: How did you name the file with the rake task and in what folder did you place it?

Comment: @spickermann updated with those details :)

Comment: Rake tasks usually have extension `.rake` not `.rb`, and they also live in `/lib/tasks`, try renaming, moving and see if anything helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From to the [Rails guides about Custom Rake tasks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks):

> Custom rake tasks have a `.rake` extension and are placed in `Rails.root/lib/tasks`. You can create these custom rake tasks with the `bin/rails generate task` command.

That means your file should be named like this:

```
lib/tasks/update_zendesk.rake
```

Note the file extension `.rake` instead of `.rb`.